# Android tablet will not let me install more than one app at a time

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have 3 .apk files in the Android folder on my xoom tablet but every time i try to install one of them when one of the others is already installed it keeps telling me that it will overwrite the previous application and it does just that. How do i go about installing all 3 of them? thanks

Comment: **Alextsc** right. Have tried this with different package name or same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have to have three different package names, which is most likely not the case here. 
If the package name is the same for all three, they will be treated as different versions of the same app *(and and an installation will work as an update, overwriting the previous version)*.

Comment: i tried going back in my code and changing the package names in eclipse to all something different. i replaced all .apk files on the tablet after rebuilding them. Installed one of them. the next one that i try to install, it says "The application that you are installing will replace another application"

Comment: I looked into this more closely and instead of trying to install the apps, i opened up the app manager to look at more information. the package name was all the same and the LABEL for all 3 was the same as well? What in the world is that about? I looked into eclipse more closely and under the "gen" folder(generated java files) the package name for this folder for each separate project was still the old package names. I tried to refactor,rename these package name and what it does it create the new package name, not replace the old one.Tried manually deleting the old one and it comes right back.

Comment: The R.Java files inside each package indeed has the old package name while i have obviously a different R.Java file for the new unique package that created - again when i try to delete the old package name it recreates it on the spot. any ideas?

Comment: Delete the R.java generated files, and it will auto-generate the new ones. Also, try changing the name of the apps, as sometimes it tends to mess up (for some reason) if you have the exact same app name.

Comment: when i try to change manually the package name, to match the package name that i refactored for the project, it says " R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!" - And the generated version is the old package name. To make sure i am clear, all the projects have different names. So I have ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectC and of course these represent the main class of the activity that it creates. So originally they were already named differently, i had just gave them all the same package name. When i had all 3 .apk files on the tablet, i opened them in the app manager(cont..)

Comment: ...(cont) and they had still the same package name and the same LABEL - meaning the LABEL in my example would be ProjectA

Comment: Changing package names can get somewhat complicated at times in my experience. It seems like a straightforward task, but it's not. Start by right clicking on your project(s) and select `Android tools -> Rename Application Package`. Then go though your AndroidManifest and see if you got any remains. Then make sure that you don't get any error in the *Problems* tab, often you get ones that prevent resource generation, which means no generated APK in the end. When you've done that, clean your project via `Project -> Clean`.

Comment: That seemed to work alextsc. Evidently refactor->rename doesn't work in this case. Thanks for the help! *Accepted*